# click event of checkbox in gridview, how to know it was checked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a checkbox column in gridview and getting its Click event. But I just has relised I do not need Click event rather I need to know the events if checkbox is checked or unchecked on Client side. But these events are not available.

Please guide how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

use delegate on the column by setting a css class to the checkboxs.
then listen to the click event of these checkboxes and check the .checked property of the actual dom element

Comment: Avi thanks

But how I can know which checkbox it was ? I cannot use this keyword as I am also passing some argument from server code to html, which is later passed to javascript.

Any suggestion plz.

Comment: it has been a while since i last touched a gridview, 
and i don't fully understand what you are trying to do(maybe add some code to your question)
but as i recall, you can hook to the rowDataBinding and at this stage you have access to the item being bound - just add the identifier to the row, and then from the event of the checkbox use $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-id"), you can also add this identifier to the checkbox, but i guess you will need it in other places too

Answer (score 1):

You can still use your click event.  Inside of the function use:

```
$('#mycheckbox').click(function()
{
   if($(this).prop('checked'))
   {
      //Do something here
   }
   else
   {
      //Do something else here
   }
});
```

Comment: Kyle, I have checkboxes in grid. What should I use in selector in place of $('#mycheckbox').click....

Plz guide

Comment: You can do one of two things.  Either add a class to every checkbox and change $('#mycheckbox') to #('.mycheckbox') or add an event listener to the entire grid and then quickly find what generated the event.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably looking to check that the checkbox input `is(":checked")`

Check out my example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RWCZK/

```
$("#checked").click(function()
{
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
    $("#show").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#show").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Luke for this valuable input.

It is a checkbox in asp.net grid. Please guide what selctor I should use instread of $("#checked").click(function() ?

Thanks

Comment: If this is the only checkbox in the grid, if you put a `CssClass` on the grid, you can then use the class and checkbox selector and find which checkbox has been clicked: `$(".gridcss :checkbox")...`